# Deploying a project with web references

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I have a project that uses web references to make SOAP calls to several web services.

When I'm working locally, the services are hosted on my local machine, so the URL of each web service is something like http://localhost/blah.

When I deploy the project to a server, the URL needs to change to the production URL.

Currently I am accomplishing this with a prebuild event that does a find-and-replace on each URL and overwrites it with the deployment URL before deploying.  Surely there is a better way.

Can someone enlighten me on the best way to change web references for deployment?

This happens to be a VB.NET project in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the URL behavior of the Web reference to dynamic, the application obtains the URL at run time from the appSettings element of your application's configuration file.

So, you can use code to set it based on where it is deployed.  This is a pretty old link, but I think it should help:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/wsdldynamicurl.aspx